# Isomorphism between the hom complexes $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B[n])$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)[n]$

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $A$ and $B$ be chain complexes of $k$-modules. Is there an isomorphism or a homotopy equivalence between the hom complexes $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B[n])$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)[n]$?

I tried with the map $f\mapsto (-1)^nf,$ but it does not commute with the differentials.

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is any justice in the world it should be $f \mapsto f$...

Comment: Unfortunately the degreewise identity map is not a chain map between these two complexes. In fact, on the one hand we have $d_{\mathrm{Hom}(A,B[n])}(f)=(-1)^nd_B\circ f+(-1)^{\mathrm{deg(f)}+1}f\circ d_A$, and on the other hand $d_{\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)[n]}(f)=(-1)^nd_B\circ f+(-1)^{\mathrm{deg(f)}+n+1}f\circ d_A.$

Comment: Hmmm. I think you may be confused by the notation. If $f$ has degree $d$ as a morphism $A \to B [n]$ then it has degree $d - n$ (or $d + n$, depending on your convention...) as a morphism $A \to B$, right? Either way, it cancels out the "extra" factor of $(-1)^n$.

Comment: I'd say it follows directly from the definition of the hom complex: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A8H am I missing something?

Comment: @ZhenLin you're right, I have to consider $f\in\mathrm{Hom}^d(A,B)[n]$ as an element of degree $d+n.$ Thanks for the help.